# Process output with `awk` when the command prompts for input with no newlines

Tags: bash, maven, awk

I have a process (Apache maven) that produces lots of output, of which I want to colorize some parts. Specifically, if the line starts with `[INFO]` I want that initial substring to be in blue color, with all other text left unchanged.

Here's a simplified version of my script named `color-maven`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

export BLUE=`tput setaf 4`
export RESET=`tput sgr0`

function mvn-color() {
    ( mvn $@ | awk "BEGIN { RS = \" \" } ; { sub(/\[INFO\]/, \"${BLUE}[INFO]${RESET}\"); printf \"\%s \", \$0 }" )
}

mvn-color archetype:generate
```

Example output (all the initial `[INFO]` are colored in blue in the shell), where `<enter>` marks where the program asks for my input:

```
$ ./color-maven
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[...cut...]
1192: remote -> uk.ac.rdg.resc:edal-ncwms-based-webapp (-)
<enter>
Choose a number or apply filter: 497: Choose org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart version:
1: 1.1
```

In the above, the text `Choose a number or apply filter: 497:` is the prompt for some user input. Compare it with the normal execution of the `mvn` command without using my script:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[...cut...]
1192: remote -> uk.ac.rdg.resc:edal-ncwms-based-webapp (-)
Choose a number or apply filter: 497: <enter>
Choose org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart version:
1: 1.1
```

Why is the prompt not appearing immediately on screen if I process the output of `mvn` with my `awk` script? How do I preserve the same output structure of the original `mvn` command and modify only the initial `[INFO]` string of all lines?

Comment: Its the script that will wait for the newline, awk will just process whatever is given to it as it is given. If you don't want the blank line just use `NF{command}` in awk so only lines with characters on are processed. Or if what you want is it to run in parallel then you will have to integrate it into the script or run it parallel not in a pipe.

Comment: Just call awk on whatever input you have. If you need to stop collecting input before a newline, how to do that is a shell question. It's very unclear what it is you're doing though - do you really need to include all of that text in your question to demonstrate your problem for us? Also, your quoting and the way you are accessing the value of shell variables in awk are both dangerously wrong.

Comment: @Jidder how is the script waiting for the newline? Bare in mind that `mvn` is not a script, it's a (Java) program. The prompt `Choose a number or...` is displayed immediately if I invoke `mvn` directly without the `mvn-color` wrapper

Comment: @EdMorton the problem statement is in the first 4 lines of my question, I thought giving exact details would improve the explanation of it. I will try to improve the text. Could you please elaborate on the quoting / shell reference issues?

Comment: What does happen if you don't pipe to awk? Does it expect a newline too?

Comment: @hek2mgl no. I updated the question with the regular output without any `awk` processing

Comment: Can you put the whole output onto a pastebin and post the link here? Then I could possibly reproduce it. Of course you need to make sure that the file does not contain sensitive data.

Comment: the function body as written but with appropriate quoting etc. syntax would be `mvn "$@" | awk -v b="$BLUE" -v r="$RESET" 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "} {sub(/\[INFO\]/,b"&"r)} 1`